# Laravel Eloquent Get Method Does Not Work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Well, I'm trying to get some records from db with models. My model is like this:

```
class People extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'test-connection';

    protected $table = 't_people';
}
```

And I'm trying to get them like this:

```
public function searchPopularPlayers() {
    return People::where('popularity', '<=', 10)->get();
}
```

When I use first() instead of get(), I get the first record. But I need them all. I get null when I use get(). Any help??

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Errors?

Comment: Return as null. No error

Comment: this shouldnt happen. `first()` gets you the first object, `get()` should at least return an array with 1 element then.

Comment: @Flame I've expected that, but that's the problem.